# Interviewer Never Called?

Tags: interviewing, applications, phone

I saw a question similar to this one:
Basically I received and confirmed via Email a phone interview for 1:30pm EST/ 10:30am PST (different time zones). The interviewer then emailed me and asked to reschedule to a later time (2:15pm EST- 11:15am PST) of the same day saying she double booked. I agreed- well the time came and went. I double checked my email and the times to make sure there were no miscommunications- there were none. I then figured maybe by some chance she had meant 2:15 PST, so I waited. Once 2:30pm PST hit I emailed her just to verify if we were still on or if she needed to reschedule- when I hadn't heard back I also called but there was no voicemail and no one picked up. It has now been 24 hours since the initial meeting time and I haven't heard anything back and I am not sure what to do.

Answer (score 7):

You have been ghosted.  Move on and never use that recruiter again.

It happens from time to time.  It has happened to me.  Apply for another job.

Comment: Why not continue applying for a job but at the same time ask the interviewer that you are still interested if they want to interview?

Answer (score 6):

When I had interviews or applied for jobs, my rule was that if I didn't hear back in two weeks, I followed up once, and if I didn't hear from them after that, I moved on.

If they had every intention of interviewing you and had other issues (interview for other person ran longer, forgotten the time, miscommunication), they would have called back and said, "Sorry I didn't get back to you - can we reschedule for X?"

I think this particular interviewer forgot AND didn't want to admit it, so they decided to ghost you instead.  It's rude, unprofessional, and a signal to move on.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily ghosted. It's possible that the person was dragged into something else. Give it some time (say 3 days) and see if you get a response back.

If not then just move on.

The number of times that haven't got the interview call, due to agent to HR to interviewer miss communication.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried contacting the main line of the company and see if you can track her down?  She may have had a major family crisis and had to step out for a few days.  Even if you don't reach her, you may get someone close to her who could fill in the details, or has picked up her duties.

If you do reach her, I hope there is a really good reason for missing the interview.  Depending on what actually happened, this is very unprofessional behavior to drop the ball on an interview like this, and I wouldn't really want to work at a company that intentionally treats someone like this.